# localhost: Some bootstrap styles not working in Chrome, but still working in UC browser

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, localhost, uc-browser

I am doing a CMS project in php. The site has two parts: Admin panel and Home. Everything was alright but suddenly my pc ran into a problem and restarted automatically, after that when I started my site using localhost, certain bootstrap and css styles(navigation bar, pagination and some more) are not working properly, but when I run localhost on UC browser it is working fine, but in chrome and edge the styles are broken. Can you explain why its happening?
Also strange that when in chrome, the admin panel styles are all okey, but home page styles are broken. I inspected both uc and chrome, they are using different bootstrap versions!

I checked bootstrap and css paths they are okey, the thing is that site is working properly in UC browser but not in Chrome and Edge.

Comment: Did you refresh the cache ?

Comment: Yes but same as before :/

Comment: Have you tried using Chrome DevTools to track down the issue with styles?
You will at least find what exactly is going om with styles

Comment: yes, for example this is the style of navbar in UC which is working fine:
.navbar {
    position: relative;
    min-height: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
}
but this is in chrome's
.navbar {
    position: relative;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-pack: justify;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
    justify-content: space-between;
    padding: .5rem 1rem;
}

Comment: Clear your cache and/or CTRL-F5; what happens?

Comment: I cleared cache but same, and CTRL+F5 refreshes the page..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is solved. My Home page was using different version of bootstrap which was newer version. I changed to the older version of bootstrap then the problem solved. Still confused that why UC browser was using the older version.